# Symfony login form bad credenticals

Tags: php, symfony

For several days, I have been struggling with the symfony 3.4 login form.
No matter what I do, the error `Invalid credentials.` always appears.

I'm now totally tired because of it.
There is no more detail about the problem.

Below are the details of a new, clean project that expectorate out this error.

**~\src\AppBundle\Controller\LoginController.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/logowanie", name="logowanie")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function logowanieAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils) {
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUserName = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('Login/logowanie.html.twig', array(
            'error' => $error,
            'lastUserName' => $lastUserName
        ));
    }

}
```

**~\app\Resources\views\Login\logowanie.html.twig**

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}AppBundle:Login:logowanie{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% if error %}
        {{ error.messageKey }}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="{{ path('logowanie') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="login">Login:</label>
                <input type="text" name="_login" id="login" value="{{ lastUserName }}" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Hasło:</label>
                <input type="password" name="_password" id="password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-info pull-right">Zaloguj</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**~\src\AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadUserData.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LoadUserData extends Fixture implements ContainerAwareInterface {

    private $container;

    /**
     * Load data fixtures with the passed EntityManager
     *
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setLogin('admin');
        $user->setEmail('admin@admin.admin');
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user, '123qwe');
        $user->setPassword($password);

        echo get_class($encoder);

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

**~\app\config\security.yml**

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: login

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: logowanie
                check_path: logowanie
```

Fixtures loaded successful, "admin" has been added to database (MySQL on VPS).
Everything works fine but not authentication.
app_dev without errors, logs showing only "INFO"

Any ideas?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
~/src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="login", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $login;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set login
     *
     * @param string $login
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLogin($login)
    {
        $this->login = $login;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get login
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     * <code>
     * public function getRoles()
     * {
     *     return array('ROLE_USER');
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return (Role|string)[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return [
            'ROLE_USER'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="isActive", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the username used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * @return string The username
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**
• `echo get_class($encoder)` in fixture load return: `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder`

• Updated User class

• I've tried to login with http_basic method and it works, but login via form still shows invalid credentials.

Comment: Add echo get_class($encorder) in your fixture.  Curious to see what class you are getting.

Comment: Can you provide your AppBundle/Entity/User class? Specifically does it implement the UserInterface interface?

Comment: @dchao5 - Added User entity. There is UserInterface implemented.

Comment: Implement getUsername() to return the login property.

Comment: I would suggest to read [How to Load Security Users from the Database (the Entity Provider)](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/entity_provider.html). There's also an example for a working `User` class in the docs.

Comment: @radon66 - Is there some example for traditional login form? Because basic http authentication is working fine!
I think the problem point is in the security firewalls, but don't know where. I've tried to add providers but still do not works.

Comment: @Invictus: Here's an example for [How to Build a Traditional Login Form](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/form_login_setup.html). But you have to fix your implementation of the `User` class as @Cerad already pointed out! See my first link for an working `User` entity (+`security.yml` configuration).

Comment: @Cerad - sorry, I missed your comment. I already thought that it's the point, but unfortunately not.
I have update of my code.

Comment: @radon66 - I focused too much on security and at the beginning did not notice these methods.